# Add text to a textarea with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, text, editor

Again I got a problem with JavaScript, but this time is something more complex.

I'm trying to make a little JavaScript text editor. Basically it's an experiment, a test and the thing should be easy. I have a `<h1>` HTML element, and a `<p>` HTML element, and both of them change, as the user writes on a `<input type="text" />` element and a `<textarea></textarea>`.

Now, everything work fine, but there is a problem. For making a space between lines, the user can't just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but of course need to use the `<br />` HTML tag.

So my idea was to make a little button that allows the user to add this tag by pressing that button.

And JavaScript just makes a variable of the actual text, save it and add at the end of it the `<br />`. The result should be the text written by the user plus the break HTML tag.

And this works, if the textarea is empty and if you have never written something on it. It works and work even 10 or 20 times, but if you write something on it, it just stop working, even if you delete all the text. What is the problem in the code below?

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Text editor</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">

        <style>
            .title {
                font-family: roboto;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .text {
                font-family: roboto slab;
                text-align: justify;
                margin-bottom: 40px;
            }
            .container {
                width: 80%;
            }
            .textarea {
                width: 100%;
                height: 30em;
                text-indent: 0.5em;
            }
            .title_box {
                margin: 10px;
                width: 20em;
                padding: 10px;
                font-size: 1em;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <center>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="title" id="title_space">Title of the page</h1>
            <p class="text" id="text_space">Content of the page.</p>
        </div>
        </center>
        <hr />
        <center><input type="text" class="title_box" placeholder="Title" id="title_box" /></center>
        <textarea class="textarea" id="text_box"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="saveText()" />
        <input type="submit" value="br" onclick="br()" />

        <script>
            function saveText(){
                var title = document.getElementById("title_box").value;
                var text = document.getElementById("text_box").value;

                document.getElementById("title_space").innerHTML = title;
                document.getElementById("text_space").innerHTML = text;
            }

            function br(){
                var actualtext = document.getElementById("text_box").value;
                var processedtext = actualtext + "<br />";
                document.getElementById("text_box").innerHTML = processedtext;
            }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're updating the text area, instead of:

```
document.getElementById("text_box").innerHTML = processedtext;
```

Use:

```
document.getElementById("text_box").value = processedtext;
```

Comment: What is the explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this to your JavaScript code just before changing the text

`text = text.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br>');`

Line breaks are \r\n or \n while HTML line break is `<br>` and that is the problem.

This in case I understood your question correctly.

[Here is the code running](https://jsbin.com/yetewexuke/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: The problem is not that <br /> is not working when i click "save" the problem is that the button won't write <br /> if i write something in the text area, but it work if I refresh the page and click the button br first write anything, any ideas about why that happen? Thanks. try to run the code snippet to see what's the actual problem is.

Comment: This solution should be working when typing anything in the text area and press `Enter` as new line so you can get rid of the 'br' button completely. As I understand, this is your problem, right ?Also, the <br> is inserted by the way but it wont be visible since it's html tag. You can inspect element in your browser and confirm that it's added. I'm updating the answer to add the full working code without the br button. Let me know if that is not what you want.